# Bootstrap div / rows not positioning correct

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

I am fairly new with bootstrap, however I am trying to create a basic website. I have the below code in my index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>BoonRadio: Playing the latest hits for you!</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="http://../bootstrap/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css"></style><style id="holderjs-style" type="text/css">.holderjs-fluid {font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-family:sans-serif;margin:0}</style><style type="text/css"></style></head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        var bustcachevar=1 //bust potential caching of external pages after initial request? (1=yes, 0=no)
        var loadedobjects=""
        var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname
        var bustcacheparameter=""

        function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
        var page_request = false
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
        page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
    try {
        page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    } 
    catch (e){
    try{
        page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    }
        catch (e){}
    }
}
    else
        return false
            page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
            loadpage(page_request, containerid)
        }
    if (bustcachevar) //if bust caching of external page
        bustcacheparameter=(url.indexOf("?")!=-1)? "&"+new Date().getTime() : "?"+new Date().getTime()
        page_request.open('GET', url+bustcacheparameter, true)
        page_request.send(null)
    }

        function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
    if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
    document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText
    }

        function loadobjs(){
        if (!document.getElementById)
        return
        for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        var file=arguments[i]
        var fileref=""
        if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file)==-1){ //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
        if (file.indexOf(".js")!=-1){ //If object is a js file
        fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
        }
        else if (file.indexOf(".css")!=-1){ //If object is a css file
        fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
        }
        }
        if (fileref!=""){
        document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
        loadedobjects+=file+" " //Remember this object as being already added to page
        }
    }
}
</script>

  <body style="">

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">BoonRadio</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Our DJ's</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Apply for DJ</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Timetable</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </li>
          </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

        <div class="container">
            <img src="../img/banner.png" />
                  <div class="page-header"></div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8" style="float: left;">
                            <div class="panel panel-info">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam iaculis tincidunt nunc eu iaculis. Curabitur aliquam, purus volutpat tincidunt fermentum, augue erat 
                          scelerisque dui, at aliquet leo lectus quis dui. Nulla congue elit in lacus porttitor, ultricies ultrices ligula porttitor. Praesent faucibus ullamcorper ligula ut 
                          cursus. Vivamus condimentum augue vel dapibus feugiat. Proin vulputate massa at tortor iaculis, in sodales nulla suscipit. Pellentesque commodo venenatis mauris, 
                          vitae feugiat tortor cursus non. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc quam nisi, semper non tortor vel, tincidunt eleifend dui. 
                          Curabitur pellentesque, nulla eu blandit condimentum, augue ante posuere nunc, at laoreet velit est ac ipsum. Vivamus neque elit, pellentesque eu justo a, 
                          iaculis lacinia leo. Sed pulvinar dapibus diam et vulputate. In porta sem id lorem vestibulum pulvinar. Suspendisse luctus lorem sit amet condimentum volutpat. 
                          Nullam id pharetra tortor.
                          <br /><br />

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4" style="float: right;">
                        <div class="panel panel-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Radio Statistics</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                                Statics code here.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Quick Requests</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                                Request line code here.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Facebook</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                                Facebook code here.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
                </div>


                    <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
                        ajaxpage('#', 'contentarea')
                        </script>
                        <div id="contentarea"></div> -->

                  <div class="page-header"></div>
                  <div class="footer">&copy; BoonRadio 2013</div>
                </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/holder.js"></script>


</body></html>
```

Don't mind the hidden ajax code. Anyways, my divs are doing this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEaSn.png

The more I add in the main content box, the further down the 3 divs on the right go down. I am wanting them to stay in place so when I add more content, they don't move down. Even adding margin-top to the col-sm-4 div, they still move down.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uYVZ.png

It might be simple and I'm just not thinking properly, but would someone assist me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how Bootstrap's grid system works. Get rid of the float styles on your column divs and it should work; Bootstrap already provides the correct float styles as part of the grid system. Also you have a stray `</li>` in your nav header. Also, get your indenting sorted out, it's super inconsistent right now, which makes it harder to read and harder to figure out.

Comment: Thank you! It was also me placing the </div> for the specific rows in the wrong place. I've removed the float styles as well as as the stray </li>. Thanks for the advice on indenting as well.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your indenting. There were some closing `</div>` tags that were unnecessary. As Nathan said, the floating css is not needed with Bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="../img/banner.png" />
    <div class="page-header"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Lorem ipsum ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Radio Statistics</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Statics code here.
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-info">
                 <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Quick Requests</h3>
                 </div>
                 <div class="panel-body">
                     Request line code here.
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-info">
                 <div class="panel-heading">
                     <h3 class="panel-title">Facebook</h3>
                 </div>
                 <div class="panel-body">
                     Facebook code here.
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
     </div>
     <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
         ajaxpage('#', 'contentarea')
     </script>
     <div id="contentarea"></div> -->
     <div class="page-header"></div>
     <div class="footer">&copy; BoonRadio 2013</div>
</div>
```